# Web Page Source Annotation Tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

```
<ul class="contact">
<li class="first">Carnegie Mellon University</li>
<li>5000 Forbes Avenue, Pittsburgh, PA 15213</li>
</ul>
```

=>

```
<ul class="contact">
<li class="first">[univ]Carnegie Mellon University[/univ]</li>
<li>[address]5000 Forbes Avenue, Pittsburgh, PA 15213[/address]</li>
</ul>
```

shows the semantic annotation process I'd like to go through for thousands of web pages. To make my intention clear, I'd like to download all these web pages and have them annotated with user-defined tags (e.g., `univ`, `address`). The annotated pages will be used later for processing.

The most naive method I've been using is download the page, open the page file, edit the file with a text editor and save it. It's just too cumbersome.

A better approach I've been using is select the target text to be annotated from browser, inspect the target with tools like Firebug, edit the target text within the inspected view and save the edited page. This helps alleviate some burden, but still there's much room for improvement.

The ideal tool I'd like to have is one with which I can select the target text from the page within a browser, pick the corresponding  annotation tag(preferably choosing from a tool bar which displays all tags available), and save the edited page with a single button.

If anyone knows such kind of tools, it would be great. But I doubt such a tool exists at all. Chances are I have to write such a tool myself. The question is, how should I get started? I have little web application developing experience.

Should I write a browser extension? Should I write a standalone application? In what language?

**EDIT**: A simpler version of the question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271919/surrounding-selected-text-with-tags). A complete working solution is preferred. I assume this problem is no big deal for experienced web developers but it might really take a while for me and I need to implement the function as soon as possible.

**EDIT**: Also, I prefer a tool bar right after selection to a drop-down list after right click. I think the tool bar for chrome extension `Diigo Web Collector` is quite cool. 
[image]

What's more, a `save` button is needed on the tool bar to save the edited page to default or user specified place on computer. The buttons on the tool bar should be in this order: `univ` `address` `tag3` `tag4` ... `tagn` `save`. The save button comes last.

**EDIT**: It seems impossible to download the edited page to local file system using Javascript. In either Chrome or Firefox, after we edit the source code of the page in the inspected view, there's a save button for us to save the edited page to local file system. How was that implemented? What I don't want about that save button is it always prompts for the directory to download the page. I'd like to make it a default directory with my own save button.

Comment: I bet you can pull it off in a bookmarklet.

Comment: This may actually be possible to implement. Every JavaScript WYSIWYG editor deals essentially with the same problem: surrounding a content selection with a tag. I would take a look at how built-from-the-ground-up JS WYSIWYG editors implement their "bold", "italic" etc. buttons.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Can you please be a little specific? I just played with a couple Chrome bookmarklet extentions, but none of them met my needs.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Good suggestion. From my limited experience with such editors, they seem only to allow user to select the text from the source code rather than the rendered page.

Comment: @Terry nope - WYSIWYG Editors work on the end result

Comment: @TerryLi: It is possible to download edited page as `mhtml` to a sandboxed location using `pageCapture API`. Check my `Edit1`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A chrome extension can automate this functionality, you can further extend this skeleton functionality for all possibilities.

The following skeleton adds a [context menu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/contextmenu) for right click event of mouse for selection event<sup>1</sup>

A Menu is added to chrome browser and is activated when a selection is made as shown in this screen shot

### Context Menu Appearance after selection of text

[image]

<sup>**1**</sup>- **Selection context event fires when a selection of text is done by mouse click**

## Demonstration

Look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_Sud/2m8Wx/), after installation of chrome extension it annotates with user-defined tags

#### HTML Code Before

[image]

#### HTML Code After Selection

Select a `<li>` text from output console of jsfiddle through context menu added to chrome browser,you can see DOM is also changed!

[image]

## Code Reference

#### manifest.json

manifest file binds `content script(s)` and `background page(s)` to extension.

```
{
    "name": "Annotation Tool",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244498/web-page-source-annotation-tool",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "myscript.js"
            ],
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "<all_urls>",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "screen.png",
        "48": "screen.png",
        "128": "screen.png"
    }
}
```

#### background.js

Create(s) Context menu and binds it to browser and activates context menu execution through message passing.

```
var _selection_univ = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Add <univ> tag for %s ",
    "id": "_selection_univ",
    "onclick": reportclick,
    "contexts": ["selection"]
}, function () {
    console.log("Context Menu 2 Created");
});
var _selection_address = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Add <address> tag for %s ",
    "id": "_selection_address",
    "onclick": reportclick,
    "contexts": ["selection"]
}, function () {
    console.log("Context Menu 2 Created");
});
//Add number of variables here for your functionality
function reportclick(info, tab) {
    switch (info.menuItemId) {
        case "_selection_univ":
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "univ");//Notify Content Script for univ
            break;
        case "_selection_address":
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "address");//Notify Content Script for address
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Handle default case..");
    }
}
```

#### myscript.js

```
//Handle DOM Changes here
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, response) {
    switch (message) {
        //Hanlde [univ] tag 
        case "univ":
            if (document.getSelection().baseNode != null) document.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.innerHTML = "[univ]" + document.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.innerHTML + "[/univ]";
            break;
        //Hanlde [address] tag  
        case "address":
            if (document.getSelection().baseNode != null) document.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.innerHTML = "[address]" + document.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.innerHTML + "[/address]";
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Handle default case..");
    }
});
```

## Further Extension

If you want to further add few more context menu(s)

1) create a variable for context menu as shown here in `background.js`

```
var _selection_Some_Tag = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Add [SOME TAG] tag for %s ",
    "id": "_selection_univ",
    "onclick": reportclick,
    "contexts": ["selection"]
}, function () {
    console.log("Context Menu for Some Tag Created");//In Call Back
});
```

2) add a case for switch in background page as shown here

```
case "_selection_your_case":
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "_your_tag_content"); //Notify Content Script for address
    break;
```

3) handle your custom tag in content scripts by adding code as shown here

```
//Hanlde [your custom] tag 
case "univ":
    if (document.getSelection().baseNode != null) document.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.innerHTML = "[your tag]" + document.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.innerHTML + "[/your tag]";
    break;
```

## Testing and Loading Extension

Check [How to Load an Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) for testing and extending this script.

## References

- [Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html).
- [Background Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)
- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Context Menu](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html)
- [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)
- [Extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html)
- [DOM Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection)

## EDIT 1

You can use following code of chrome extension for

- **Tool Bar Instead of Context Menu**
- **Replacing only selected text**
- **Saving File to Sand Boxed Location**

To use this code use any of your fav icon(s) and put them in chrome directory for every tag `[univ]` and use corresponding names in `css file` here

> background-image: url(chrome-extension://**MSG_@@extension_id**/YOUR_ICON_NAME.png);

#### manifest.json

Registering `css and java script` for `annotation tool`.

```
{
    "name": "Annotation Tool",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244498/web-page-source-annotation-tool",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "css": [
                "myscript.css"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery.js",
                "myscript.js"
            ],
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "<all_urls>",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "screen.png",
        "48": "screen.png",
        "128": "screen.png"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "icon1.png",
        "icon2.png"
    ]
}
```

#### myscript.css

Binding Icons here.

```
#root #univ {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 100000;
    height: 22px;
    width: 26px;
    background-image: url(chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/icon1.png);
}
#root #addr {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 100000;
    height: 22px;
    width: 26px;
    background-image: url(chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/icon2.png);
}
```

#### myscript.js

Code for updating selected text with custom tags.

```
//Intialize counters to default values
clicking = false;
selecting = false;

//Set the toolbar to some invalid position so it will not appear unless a selection is made
var currentMousePos = {
    x: -100,
    y: -100
};

$(document).mousedown(function () {
    //Click is started
    clicking = true;
});

//Tool bar to add
$('body').append("<div id='root' style='position: absolute; left:" + currentMousePos.x + "px; top:" + currentMousePos.y + "px; display: block;'><a id='univ' href='javascript:void(0);'>&nbsp;</a><a id='addr' href='javascript:void(0);' >&nbsp;</a></div>");


$(document).mouseup(function (event) {
    if (selecting) {
        //He is selecting text
        $("#root").attr("style", "position: absolute; left:" + currentMousePos.x + "px; top:" + currentMousePos.y + "px; display: block;");
    } else {
        //He just clicked
        $("#root").attr("style", "display: none;");
    }
    //Reset counters
    clicking = false;
    selecting = false;
});

$(document).mousemove(function () {
    if (clicking) {
        //He did not simply click , but he is selecting some text
        selecting = true;
        //Track current position to put toolbar
        currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
        currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
    }
});

$("div #addr").click(function () {
    //Get Selected text
    var selection = document.getSelection();
    //Add your tags and prepare replacing content
    var html = "[addr]" + selection + "[/addr]";
    if (selection.getRangeAt && selection.rangeCount) {
        //Chrome supports only one range fire fox supports multiple ranges
        range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        //remove selection
        range.deleteContents();
        //Create a node
        node = range.createContextualFragment(html);
        //Add the custom node
        range.insertNode(node);
    }
});

$("div #univ").click(function () {
    //Get Selected text
    var selection = document.getSelection();
    //Add your tags and prepare replacing content
    var html = "[univ]" + selection + "[/univ]";
    if (selection.getRangeAt && selection.rangeCount) {
        //Chrome supports only one range fire fox supports multiple ranges
        range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        //remove selection
        range.deleteContents();
        //Create a node
        node = range.createContextualFragment(html);
        //Add the custom node
        range.insertNode(node);
    }
});
```

## Output1

Now You can replace any part of text

[image]

## Output 2

Replace any web page

[image]

## Saving file to chosen Location

It is possible to download the page using [chrome.pageCapture API](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/pageCapture.html), but to a `sand boxed` location.

### Sample Implementation on using pageCapture API

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Page Capture Demo",
    "description": "This demos Page Capture MHTML Functionality",
    "permissions": [
        "pageCapture"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "screen.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1"
}
```

#### popup.html

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="pushhere"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

#### popup.js

```
function capture() {
    chrome.tabs.query({
        "active": true,
        "currentWindow": true,
        "status": "complete"
    }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.pageCapture.saveAsMHTML({
            "tabId": tabs[0].id
        }, function (data) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (eventt) {
                console.log(eventt.target.result);
                document.getElementById('pushhere').innerHTML = eventt.target.result;
                //window.open(eventt.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsText(data);
            //window.open(data);
        });
    });
}
window.onload = capture;
```

Test this code using steps above by picking your icons of choice, hope this helps :)

## Edit 2

- Accessing contents of HTML File(s) `images`, `js` and `css` files is possible from chrome extension
- Accessing Local Disk System(Reading and storing data to them) is not supported from chrome extensions(for security reasons)
- You can save files to sand-boxed location which  however are not accessible for general access.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. This is very close to what I want. What if the selected text is only part of the html text within the enclosing html tags? For example, I'd like to select **Carnegie Mellon** instead of the entire **Carnegie Mellon University**.

Comment: Also, I prefer a tool bar to a drop-down list. See my edited question. A save button is needed to save the edited page with one single click to default or user specified place on computer.

Comment: @TerryLi: I have added code for **tool bar** and and to **add tags for part of selected text**, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @TerryLi: Now when **Carnegie** is selected from `Carnegie Mellon University` it turns like  `[univ]Carnegie[/univ] Mellon University`.

Comment: The tool bar works. Thanks again. For the save function, I only want the html document of the page. Can you incorporate the capture extension into the tool bar one so that the save button is the last on the tool bar and right after univ, addr button? So when I click the save button from the tool bar, it will save the html of the page  to a default location(e.g., C://annotations).

Comment: @TerryLi:Check my `edit 2`, accessing local file system from chrome extensions is not possible till date.

Answer (score 0):

A browser extension should be fine. A standalone application would need to utilize a full-fledged browser, which is cumbersome.

Only with a browser extension (in contrast to a bookmarklet) you would have the permission to save the results directly to the filesystem. You can add the "Annotate" button to the browser (G)UI as well.

However, storing thousands of HTML files on your harddisk might not be your aim. Instead, you could set up a simple database server to which you post the annotation results. A small bookmarklet with some ajax code would be enough on the clientside then.