# How to add lightbox to context menu within a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, lightbox, slimbox

I'm building a Chrome extension based on Context Menu.
When the user either selects a link or highlight a text the extension will appear ("contexts":["selection","link"]...).

As soon as the user clicks the option desired, how do I know to bring up a lightbox or slimbox effects to have an iframe with the results of a search based on the parameter passed?

Example: 
Selected text "hello world" within any page while browsing in Chrome >> right-click to have my context menu extension to appear >> selected Option 1 >> lightbox or slimbox will appear and an iframe displaying google search results for the selected text previously (hello world).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244498/web-page-source-annotation-tool/14291965#14291965) is a good start it covers all possibilites, let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: Thank you Sudharshan, but the article you've suggested didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a summary of how to do this:

1. Request necessary permissions, such as content scripts permission
2. Add the context menu item.
3. In you onclick handler for the context menu item, send a message to a content script, like so:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
       chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {"action": "startLightbox"});
    });
   ```
4. Have the content script add a lightbox to the page.

   ```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
         if ( request.action == "startLightbox" ) {
            //code for lightbox here
         }
       })
   ```

I came across your question when I was trying to figure it out myself. Once I figured it out, I thought I would share it. [Here is my tutorial with detailed instructions](http://bryangentry.us/make-google-chrome-extension-launch-lightbox-user-clicks-context-menu/).