# get selected text in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the selected text from a tab in chrome extensions. currently i am using message passing between popup.js and a content script to get the selected text.is there a method of getting selected text from popup.js itself?

Answer (score 2):

Popup Page and Content scripts live in individual environments, to establish a channel of communication you need to use message passing mechanism.

Do you see any issues in using message passing?

Comment: i also want to get the dom structure of the selected text. is there a way possible using content scripts.

Comment: @ManthanPatel: Yes, it is possible, try [this annotation post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244498/web-page-source-annotation-tool/14291965#14291965) it can help you.